# Can't open Windows Forms application with Entity Framework from other computers

Tags: entity-framework

I wrote my program using Entity Framework, I work on a local network, and I want to run the program on other machines, but it does not work at all, but it works on the local machine only, so what is the reason for that? I want help

Comment: Do you get any errors ? If so - what are they?